# How to override camera permission & error handling?

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, ar.js

I am building a web app using ar.js.

When I embed the aframe.js & aframe-ar.js,
Browser ask camera permission automatically after page loaded.

I would like to have a tutorial first for my site,
How can I manage the permission gaining action manually?

Second question, How can I override the error handling?
(ps: all errors are handle by alert box by default)

```
<!-- include a-frame -->
<!-- include ar.js for aframe -->
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.min.js"></script>
<script>ARjs.Context.baseURL = '/three.js/'</script>

<!-- start the body of your page -->
<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <a-scene embedded arjs>
    <a-marker preset="hiro">
            <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='color: yellow;'></a-box>
    </a-marker>
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
</body>
```